# Calling SetInterval function expressions

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

Ok so within my imgInt function I am calling another function "nextPhoto" from within. Although when I mouseOut of my image element I want to recall imgInt although I don't know what way to call it or if I may have to pass any parameters into it.

```
var imgInt = setInterval(function(){
    nextPhoto("next");
}, 2000);

image.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    clearInterval(imgInt);
    this.addEventListener("onmouseout", function(){
        setInterval(imgInt);
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: The argument to `setInterval()` has to be a function, not a value returned by a previous `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restart a previous interval by passing it to `setInterval`. Define a function that starts the interval, and call that.

```
var imgInt;
function startInterval() {
    imgInt = setInterval(function(){
        nextPhoto("next");
    }, 2000);
}
startInterval();
image.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    clearInterval(imgInt);
});
image.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    startInterval();
});
```

It's almost always wrong to add one event listener inside another listener function, because it creates multiple listeners every time the first event occurs.

Comment: I believe you forgot to erase the `imageInt();` line, `imgInt` is never a function, just an interval id.

Comment: @Ricky Right, that was supposed to be `startInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up on Mr. @Barmar answer.

The [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) method returns a unique interval ID (*timeoutID*).

> The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin
>   repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely
>   identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling
>   clearInterval().

This method is expecing a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) as first parameter, followed by a delay in milliseconds and optionally N parameters which are passed through to the function passed as the first parameter once the timer expires.

```
var intervalID = scope.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
```

---

```js
(function() {

  var imgInt,
    image = document.querySelector("img");

  function startInterval() {
    imgInt = setInterval(function(param1, param2) {
        //               ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^ ^
        //              Function  param1  param2 N
        //nextPhoto("next");
        console.log(imgInt);
        //          ^^^^^^
        //     numeric timeoutID
        console.log(param1, param2);
        //          ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
        //       "MyParam1"    2
      }, 2000,
      // ^^^^
      // delay
      "MyParam1", 2);
    // ^^^^^^    ^^^
    // param1   param2
  }
  image.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    clearInterval(imgInt);
  });
  image.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    startInterval();
  });
})();
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/170?text=hover me" alt="Please mouseover this photo then mouseout wait 2 seconds then repeat.">
```